# Last post in the_post_navigation() not showing title

Tags: php, wordpress

I am trying to loop the posts in my the_post_navigation

I have managed to get it to work but the first and last post in the loop always displays as 'previous post' and 'next post' NOT as the title. Also the class I have applied in functions php does not apply to the last link in the loop.

How would I edit this so it would also use the title when getting the $first or $last post

Here is my php for the loop

```
    div class="custom-post-nav">

        <div class="nav-house">             

        <div class="left-post-arrow"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/edinburgh-arrow.png"></div>

       <div class="post-nav-function">

       <!-- <?php the_post_navigation(); ?>  -->
       <?php /* Infinite next and previous post looping */
          if( get_adjacent_post(false, '', true) ) { 
          previous_post_link('%link');

} else { 

        $first = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=1&order=DESC'); 
        $first->the_post();
        echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">Previous Post</a>';
        wp_reset_query();
                                            }; 

 if( get_adjacent_post(false, '', false) ) { 
        next_post_link('%link');
        } else { 
        $last = new WP_Query('posts_per_page=1&order=ASC'); 
        $last->the_post();
        echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">Next Post</a>';
        wp_reset_query();
        }; 

        ?>
        </div>          

        <div class="right-post-arrow"><img src="/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/edinburgh-arrow.png"></div>
       </div>
```

This is the php to add classes

```
function add_class_next_post_link($html){
    $html = str_replace('<a','<a class="nav-next"',$html);
    return $html;
}
add_filter('next_post_link','add_class_next_post_link',10,1);

function add_class_previous_post_link($html){
    $html = str_replace('<a','<a class="nav-previous"',$html);
    return $html;
}
add_filter('previous_post_link','add_class_previous_post_link',10,1);
```

I've tried putting:

```
echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '"><?php the_title(); ?</a>';
```

but no luck

You can see the issue [here](https://www.shereewalker.com/illustration-edinburgh/dishoom/)

Comment: _“but for some reason”_ …??? Are you wondering now that your script does exactly what you implemented, or what? `echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">Previous Post</a>';`, `echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">Next Post</a>';` – that’s where those link texts come from …

Comment: @04FS - I have very limited knowledge of php, I got this loop code from another website and therefore did not initially understand why it does not use the titles for the first and last post. I have edited the question 

Basically I don't know how to edit the else statement to also get the title for the beginning / end of the last loop.

Comment: Well replace the static parts that say “previous / next post” right now, with a function call that gets the title for the current post inside the loop then …?

Comment: @04FS I don't know how to do that. I've tried putting 'get_the_title' in place of the static text but I can't get the syntax right.

Comment: I just tried

`echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '"><?php the_title(); ?></a>';` but again no luck

Comment: `<?php` inside a string that you output via `echo` makes no sense - you already _are_ in a PHP parser section here. Try `echo '<a href="' . get_permalink() . '">'. get_the_title() .'</a>';` instead.

Comment: This works thankyou - though the class still does not apply to the first and last post meaning I cannot style them

Comment: I managed to fix the class issue by splitting up the php code into left navigation and right navigation wrapped in divs - that way I could float the right navigation to the right. Thanks for your help. I could mark this as the answer if it was not in a comment?